# Network printer not visible to lookupPrintServices on Windows Server 2008 JBoss EAP 6.3.0

Tags: java, printing, jboss, windows-server-2008-r2

I have JBoss EAP 6.3.0 running as a Windows 2008 service under an Active Directory user account in the Admin group. A network printer (model KONICA MINOLTA 423SeriesPS) was connected to this user by RDPing in using its account, then connecting to the printer via its `\\server\printerName` path. This printer was also made the default printer for that user. Then I bring up the JBoss service and my application EAR loads. It contains a WAR file that looks for printers using PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null). The only printer returned is the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer". What's wrong?

**UPDATE**
I found this error in the Windows Event Viewer. Seems somewhat unlikely to be related, as there are many of these from before that user and printer were created, but for what it's worth:

```
The print spooler failed to load a plug-in module TPVMMon.dll, error code 0x7e See the event user data for context information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that network printers configured as such will not reliably appear in the list of printers returned from `PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices` or `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices()`, at least in Windows Server 2008 with Java 1.7. (Oddly, there do seem to be conditions under which network printers *do* show up for accounts other than Local System, but I haven't established exactly what they are.) In order to get them to show up reliably for any Active Directory user:

1. Go to the Devices and Printers panel of Control Panel
2. select "Add"
3. specify "Local Printer"
4. specify "Local Port"
5. for the port, enter the Windows path of a network printer
6. finish up the wizard

Network printers configured this way will always show up. At least they do for me.